# How can I configure JBoss so that I have to manually start and stop the server after deploying?

Tags: jboss

I want to configure this so that it doesn't restart automatically, but I have to manually start and stop it. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if I understand you correct: you just don't want to hot deploy application. You would like that application should be deployed only during starting the JBoss server?

If yes, you can disable the hot deploy service just by removing the `hdscanner-jboss-beans.xml` from `deploy` directory.

PS. It works for JBoss AS 5.1.